# Login in ajax, server 302 redirect, $_POST empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to make a login in ajax, from the main page when a button get clicked the function doLogin() is called

```
function doLogin(){
    $.post(root+"/ajax/login.php",
        {"username" : $("input#username").val(),"password" : $("input#password").val()},
        function(data, status){
            if(status=="success"){
                removeOverlay()
                $(data).prependTo($("body"));
            }
        }
    );
}
```

It should send the username and the password to the login.php page, but the $_POST array in login.php is empty, I tried to check the requests done and there are 2 requests done to the login.php page.

In the first one there are the correct POST data, but the server return a 302 status code and it redirect me to the login.php.

The second request is probably the result of the redirect and it doesn't contain the post data, so in the end the result is that login.php doesn't receive them.

I want to point out that I've done nothing to configure a 302 redirect.

How can i make the login page receive the post data, or even better: how can i prevent this 302 redirect?

Comment: How and when is your doLogin function called? Do you cancel the default behaviour of your submit button?

Comment: there is no form and no submit button, since i don't need the page to change i thought they wasn't needed, so i simply put an onclick event on a <input type="button">

Comment: Hard to get a complete picture with only one function posted... Please post the whole login.php page, javascript funtions, along with error messages and logs, thanks.